# When I change router-link not working jquery plugins, but when I refresh it's working

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have SPA with Laravel and I have main.js file and I set up this file in my main.blade.php file and I write some code in main.js with jquery plugins. Problem is when I change vue-router not working this plugins so main.js file, but when I refresh page everything is fine working.Any idea?

Comment: Add some code please. What have you tried so far?

Comment: If your question is how to automatically update code you should check out https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#browsersync-reloading

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with angular with using jquery plugins. As vue and angular are SPA(Single Page Application).

The reasoning for this is when the whole document loads, jquery `onDocument.ready()` will then kick off - enabling event handlers to listen and attached to HTML DOMs.

Using SPA Routers to navigate through your application will not load again everything. So jquery cannot attach listeners to your newly rendered views.

Find a way to manually initialize those jquery plugins.